# Python matplotlibs set labels/ticks in X-axis by condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, visualization

I have the plot:

[image]

And I want to chagne ths labels/ticks of the X-axis so there will be one only whenever a blue segment end or begin, with the value of

> x / 266.6667

Thus, if we look at the first time the blue line begin, the value of x is 1500 so I want to add the value 15000 / 266.667 to the x axis. 
Overall there are 4 blue segments so there should be 8 ticks in the x-Axis (One every time the blue segment begin or ends)

I drew this graph using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array(vec)
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data}).reset_index()
df['colors'] = np.where(data < 1, 'red', 'blue')
plt.scatter(df['index'], df['data'], c=df['colors'])
plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since we have no access to the data, it is hard to provide a working solution for your particular problem. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Divide your data by 266.6667 to get it in the units you want.

```
x /= 266.6667
```

Then find the points you want to label via

```
ticks = x[:-1][np.diff((y > 1).astype(int)) > 0]
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,70000,23)
y = np.array([0,0,0,2,3,5,4,3,0,0,0,0,2,3,5,5,3,0,0,0,0,4,3])

x /= 266.6667


fig, ax= plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y, c=(y > 1), cmap="bwr_r")

ticks = x[:-1][np.diff((y > 1).astype(int)) > 0]
ax.set_xticks(ticks)

plt.show()
```

[image]